# how to get update from c# event in batches

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am working on an application on which I subscribed one event, which triggers whenever the inventory items stock updated. So, whenever I am getting data in that event I am calling an API to update the stocks on shopify store. The problem occurs when the items updated in bulk like 100 items at a time which make this delegate run 100 times and sometime my shopify api exhaust due to frequently updates.

```
public void SomeMethod(Events event)
{
    event.InventoryStockUpdated += delegate (string itemNo){}
}
```

I tried to add items in list like below:

```
public void SomeMethod(Events event)
{
    var items = new List<string>();
    event.InventoryStockUpdated += delegate (string itemNo)
    {
        if(items.Count == 10)
        {
        // api request
        // Here the problem is the no is not always 10 and when the batch is less than 10 it wan't    run
        }
    }
}
```

How can I handle that situation. Either update items in bunches ? but I don't know the fix number of items updated in that batch.

I added thread.sleep(500) but that causing too much delay.

Comment: You probably want a "dead time" so you do not trigger API limits. So,  each time an event fires, you'd look if you handled one in the last x time. Yes: write to list for later handling. No: Handle it immediately and start a timer for x time, that when it fires bulk-handles the list.

Comment: Or simpler: have the eventhandler always write to a list and have a recurring timer handle whatever is in the list (if anything).

Comment: Btw: you'll _never_ want a `Thread.Sleep` in an event handler. It will make your app unresponsive by blocking the UI/Event dispatch Thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing something like this

```
 public static List<List<string>> Batch(List<string> list, int batchSize)
 {
    var result = new List<List<string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i += batchSize)
    {
       result.Add(list.GetRange(i, Math.Min(batchSize, list.Count - i)));
    }
    
    return result;
 }
```

Then you would just do this

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve" };
int batchSize = 10;

List<List<string>> batches = BatchHelper.Batch(list, batchSize);

// Output
// ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
// ["eleven", "twelve"]

foreach(var b in batches){
//Send to API 
//This will also send our final batch of (2)
}
```

If you wanted the helper to be dynamic you can take it a step further.

```
public static List<List<T>> Batch<T>(List<T> list, int batchSize)
{
    var result = new List<List<T>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i += batchSize)
    {
        result.Add(list.GetRange(i, Math.Min(batchSize, list.Count - i)));
    }

    return result;
}
```